# discord bot on_member_join send message not working

Tags: python, discord

```
File "bot.py", line 17, in on_member_join
    await channel.send('{.member} has joined the server')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

How can I fix?

PS. I already have intents on

code is here:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxx)
    await channel.send('{.member} has joined the server')
    
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxx)
    await channel.send('Goodbye, {.member}')
```

Comment: Post your bot.py file's code

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted the code, here is a short answer that may fix your problem:

Write This:

```
await message.channel.send(f'{member} has joined the server')
```

Instead of this:

```
await channel.send(f'{member} has joined the server')
```

Comment: it said message not defined

Comment: `@呂殿下-Luidenka` Sorry, You will have to write `member` instead of `.member`. I have edited my answer you can see now.

Comment: `@呂殿下-Luidenka` And also make it f-string

Comment: `@呂殿下-Luidenka` It would be great if you post your full code this is not your full code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here:

- Missing @bot.event at member join

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxx)
    await message.channel.send(member+' has joined the server')
    
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxx)
    await message.channel.send('Goodbye, '+member)
```